# Changing Button text dynamically in Python

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Could someone please explain to me why the following code does not work?

This is still an empty shell of a program and all I'm trying to do for now 
is that when I click the connect button it changes the text to disconnect. 
I would also like to change the command, but I'm sure if I'm able to change
the text I should be able to change the command as well.

Whenever I click the button it gives the following error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Rudolf/Desktop/test.py", line 5, in Connect
    if btnConnect["text"] == "Connect":
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I don't understand. it seems so simple and logical. Please help.

Code in question:

```
from tkinter import *

def Connect():   
    """Clicking the connect button"""
    if btnConnect["text"] == "Connect":
        btnConnect["text"] = "Disconnect"
    else:
        btnConnect["text"] = "Connect"

#Part in question^^

mGui = Tk()

mGui.geometry('500x420+1000+200')
mGui.title('PythonGUI')

#Variables:
cmdText = StringVar()


####################


#Heading
lblHead = Label(mGui, text='Distance Meassurement Device', font=("Helvetica", 18, "underline")).place(x=75,y=10)

#Connect Button and Label
btnConnect = Button(mGui, text = "Connect", command = Connect).place(x=20,y=70)
lblConnect = Label(mGui, text = 'Currently disconnected').place(x=20,y=100)

#Baud rate & COM port Labels
lblBaud = Label(mGui, text = 'Baud Rate : x').place(x=350,y=70)
lblCom = Label(mGui, text = 'COM port : x').place(x=350,y=90)

#Calibrate Buttons
btnCal0 = Button(mGui, text = 'Calibrate 0').place(x=20,y=200)
btnCal1 = Button(mGui, text = 'Calibrate 1').place(x=20,y=240)

#Stream Button
btnStream = Button(mGui, text = 'Stream on/off').place(x=20,y=350)

#Measurements block
lblMeasHead = Label(mGui, text = "Measurements:", font=("Helvetica", 12, "underline")).place(x=320,y=160)
lblDistanceHead = Label(mGui, text = "Distance:").place(x=320,y=190)
lblDistanceVal = Label(mGui, text = " x cm").place(x=380,y=190)
lblVelocityHead = Label(mGui, text = "Velocity:").place(x=320,y=210)
lblVelocityVal = Label(mGui, text = " x m/s").place(x=380,y=210)

#Send command block
lblCmd = Label(mGui, text = "Enter Command").place(x=330,y=295)
edtCmd = Entry(mGui,textvariable=cmdText).place(x=320,y=320)
btnSendCmd = Button(mGui, text = 'Send Command').place(x=330,y=345)



mGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: The btnConnect variable does not contain any value and is None since it holds a tkinter.place function which does not have value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating `btnConnect` as -

```
btnConnect = Button(mGui, text = "Connect", command = Connect).place(x=20,y=70)
```

`.place()` method does not return back the created `Button` object (it was actually returned by `Button()` ), it does not return back anything, so you get `None` in `btnConnect` , and this causes the issue you are getting. You should move the `.place()` to the next line. Example -

```
btnConnect = Button(mGui, text = "Connect", command = Connect)
btnConnect.place(x=20,y=70)
```

So that `btnConnect` correctly points to the created `Button` object.

You are currently creating all widgets like above(calling `.place()` immediately) , so you would encounter same issue if you try to access those widgets again later on. And most probably you would need to make similar changes to all widgets that you want to be able to access later on.